# Assigning keyboard shortcut to OSX's "New Terminal at Folder" service does not work

Tags: macos, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, services

I often use `right click > Services > New Terminal at Folder` to do terminal commands at particular place so now I wanted to assign a keyboard shortcut to it.

However, no matter what shortcut I assign to it via `System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Services` it does not work when I press it. What's going on here?

I'm on Yosemite 10.10.2

Answer (score 2):

You need to have the folder selected in Finder, just being in it doesn't work

Comment: doesn't work either way.

Answer (score 1):

[Try a different shortcut:](https://lifelongprogrammer.blogspot.com/2019/07/everything-about-file-or-folder-path-on-mac.html)

- it’s often because the shortcut we choose conflicts with other existing shortcuts.
- To check whether the shortcut assignment works, we can go to Finder menu, Finder -> Services, check whether the new shortcut is shown

Check more about [file and folder path in Mac](https://lifelongprogrammer.blogspot.com/2019/07/everything-about-file-or-folder-path-on-mac.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue - it appears that shortcut isn't working if you have the items shown in list/columns. If you show them as *icons* and select a folder, terminal window can be opened with a shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue now on 2023 with Ventura. It got solved after I logged out and logged back in.

It wasn't at all working before that, regardless of the view type (folder, list, columns, etc.). Now it works, again regardless of the view type.